# How to define last row in xlsxwriter while using add_chart

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I running a script to take rows and columns from a worksheet and use it to make charts. The problem that I am running into is that since the rows in the MSEXCEL sheet are changing, I want to add the last row in the `add_series` argument so that it will always take the limit of the chart data from row 2 till the last row.

This is the code that I am using currently (that I want to change):

```
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
chart1.add_series({
    'values': "='Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$126",
    'categories': "='Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$126",
    'data_labels': {'value': False, 'categories': False, 'series': False}
})
```

I have modified the above code to the following, but now the charts are not getting any data whatsoever.

```
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
chart1.add_series({
    'values': "='Sheet1'!$B$2:($B$ + str(last_row_number + 1)",
    'categories': "='Sheet1'!$A$2:($A$ + str(last_row_number + 1)",
    'data_labels': {'value': False, 'categories': True, 'series': False}
```

`last_row_number` in this case is a variable [`<type 'int'>`] calculated by enumerating through the worksheet column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost every interface in XlsxWriter supports `(row, col)` notation as well as `A1` range notation.

In the case of `add_series()` you can use lists like `[sheetname, first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col]`:

```
chart.add_series({
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, 125, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, 1, 125, 1],
    # ...
})

# Or:

last_row = 125

chart.add_series({
    'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, last_row, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, 1, last_row, 1],
    # ...
})
```

See the docs for [`add_series()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-add-series).

Comment: And that's why one should always go through the python function wikis 'slowly'. Thanks a million for pointing my attention to this @jmcnamara!. It's very much appreciated.